# How to read Json string with square brackets in it?

Tags: c++, json, boost, c++17

I am using c++ code to read json string to retrieve value based on specific key names. Example of my json response from web API is in array format like below.

```
 [
    {
    "username": "123456",
    "useraddress": "abc",
    "data": [
                {
                    "schedule": true,
                    "task": "abc",
                    "risk": "1",
                } 
            ],
     "date": "0000-00-00"
    }
]
```

Like the above format is the actual response. I have to retrieve date value using key "date".

My code snippet:

[Referred boost library] to read_json data.

'''

```
{

std::stringstream jsonString;

boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

jsonString << ws2s(Info).c_str();

boost::property_tree::read_json(jsonString, pt);

std::string date = pt.get<std::string>("date");

}
```

'''

'Info' in above snippet is wsstring containing json response data.

I can able to retrieve "date" if [] square brackets are removed manually. Since it is array format, if I pass without removing brackets, read_json throws error.

Can somebody help this out?

Comment: It's not valid JSON so I would start there. Make sure that you have valid JSON instead of trying to fix things. Talk to the people supplying that web API.

Comment: I noticed that you changed the title of the question but that will not get it reopened. You need to get them to fix the bug in their web API.

Comment: Ted Lyngmo is right that source of your problems is invalid JSon. Removing problematic comma fixes problem: https://godbolt.org/z/b6rs8d so bug is on the server.

Comment: Actually, they are provinding data from array. Entire result is one element of the array.

Comment: Start with link I've provided and show us [mcve] and explain what do you mean, since your last comment is completely confusing.